# Web scraping with Scrapy and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

```
<h2 class="result-item-name" data-nid="117" data-localisation="25.88872, -80.12488">
  Bal Harbour    </h2>
```

Hi everyone, I'm trying to collect the 'data-nid' and the 'data-localisation' but when I write my code :

```
'geocoordinates':['class','result-item-name','data-localisation']
```

I always get a None response.

Can you guys help me ? I am new to BeautifulSoup and I am not at ease with it.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please propvide a reproducible example and the rest of your code. It`s quite hard to help you without getting a grasp of what you`ve done so far.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!. Please follow these guidelines to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get much better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `BeautifulSoup` you can access the attributes using key-value. Just like a dictionary

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<h2 class="result-item-name" data-nid="117" data-localisation="25.88872, -80.12488">Bal Harbour    </h2>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
h2 = soup.find("h2", class_= "result-item-name")
print(h2["data-nid"])
print(h2["data-localisation"])
```

**Output:**

```
117
25.88872, -80.12488
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<h2 class="result-item-name" data-nid="117" data-localisation="25.88872, -80.12488">
Bal Harbour
</h2>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

h2 = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'result-item-name'})
print(h2['data-nid'])
print(h2['data-localisation'])
```

**Output**

```
117
25.88872, -80.12488
```